# Library not loaded - git issue

Tags: git, github

I'm using git for a project this year, but since a few days I encounter this error when I write gitk in my terminal. I'm a Mac user.

```
$ gitk
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXft.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/wish
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Any idea how I can fix that ?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Installing XQuartz worked for me.
https://www.xquartz.org/